# SqlFunctions.DatePart: error : function must be a literal string

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to use `SqlFunctions.DatePart` with a string which I change depending on parameters, however I can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
String dateArg = @"week";

var results = db.Orders
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    Completed = SqlFunctions.DatePart(@dateArg, x.Completed)
                })
                .Select(x=>x.Sum(y => y.Total))
                .ToList();
```

Fails with the following error:

> The DATEPART argument to the 'SqlServer.DATEPART' function must be a literal string.

Comment: Isn't the exception telling you *exactly* what's wrong? This just plain isn't supported, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `@dateArg` is not a literal string, it's as simple as that. `"week"` is, though.

If you need to vary the kind of `DATEPART` to group on, you'll need to split out the cases ("year", "month", "week", I'm guessing those are all that's needed). This is clumsy, but it's a result of the way compiling the expression tree down to a query operates -- just as in T-SQL itself, the first argument to DATEPART cannot be a parameter (they might as well have created separate methods `DatePartYear`, `DatePartMonth` etcetera, which would have made the restriction more obvious, and you should think of the calls like that).

Comment: What do you mean by split out the cases? If I add in an extra group by clause it wont allow me because then I have two lines both trying to group by the same column

Comment: I mean the good old-fashioned copy-paste: four separate queries that look remarkably alike save for that one literal they pass to `DatePart`. In case you're wondering: no, you cannot split that out to a separate function, because then you have the original problem again. It is possible to do it without copy-pasting code, by copying the expression tree and replacing only the string literal node, but if you ask me that's *far* more trouble than it's worth. You can split off the ".Select" and ".ToList" bits, at least.

Comment: That seems a nightmare for maintainability of my code. Oh well, if thats the best way then I guess that's my solution! Thanks.

Comment: If you confine this query (and its 4 variants) to its own method, maintainability is barely impacted, it's just slightly less convenient to modify it. Of course, if you use `DATEPART` all the time in various different queries, it's another ballgame. In this case I'd definitely look into having the `GroupBy` stuff as its own filter (returning an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, Order>>`) that you can reuse from elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone. Just use an inline if statement as follows:

```
string datePart = "week";
var results = db.Table.GroupBy(item => 
    (datePart == "quarter") ? SqlFunctions.DatePart("quarter", item.Date) :
    (datePart == "month") ? SqlFunctions.DatePart("month", item.Date) :
    SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", item.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = db.Orders
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                Completed = SqlFunctions.DatePart("week", x.Completed)
            })
            .Select(x=>x.Sum(y => y.Total))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: `@dateArg` is a perfectly valid way in C# to refer to the variable named `dateArg`.

Comment: bah, I saw @ and assume it was SQL-ish syntax.  Never done that in C#.  I'll fix my reply.